# FullCalendar - Get Date by clicking day header in agendaWeek view

Tags: header, fullcalendar

I would like to determine the date selected when clicking on the day header cell when in agendaWeek view.  I can add a click handler to those header cells, but I don't quite know how to get the date from the fullcalendar, because the dayClick event does not fire when clicking the header.  the class on these cells are fc-sun, fc-mon, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround i made myself.
It will make navigation from agendaWeek to agendaDay easy by clicking on day headers just call zumaMaker() after fullcalendar init.

```
function zumaMaker() {

 var arrayUIDays = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];
 for (var m = 0; m < arrayUIDays.length; m++) {
    var dim = ".fc-day-header.fc-widget-header.fc-" + arrayUIDays[m];
    var dok = $(dim).html();
    $(dim).attr("onclick", "zumaMethod( '" + dok + "','" + dim + "');");
    $(dim).css("cursor", "pointer");
    }
}

function zumaMethod(doma, diver) {

  var date = doma.split(" ")[1].split("/");
  var day = date[0];
  var month = date[1];
  var year = date[2];
  var off_date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + "00:00:00";

  $("#pl_tbl").fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
  $("#pl_tbl").fullCalendar('gotoDate', off_date);
  $(diver).css("cursor", "pointer");
  $(diver).attr("onclick", "zumaMethodRevert();");
}

function zumaMethodRevert() {
  $("#pl_tbl").fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
  zumaMaker();
}
```

Also you can add this css to customize the day headers on hover.

```
.fc-day-header:hover {
   background-color: orange;
}
.fc-day-header {
   background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has answered yet he is what I did.  The agenda viewObject has the start and end dates of the current week being displayed.  I created an array that contained all of the dates for the week displayed.  I then used JQuery to select all the th header cells and added a date attribute to each th tag.  I also added a click event to each th tag and retrieved the date attribute when the header is clicked.  This process must be executed as each new week is displayed.

Comment: glad you figured out a solution. i think this might be best as a built-in feature to fullcalendar (as it is more of a usability problem than anything). can you enter a feature request into the issue tracker? (http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list)

Comment: @arshaw, We are also looking for this. Is that implemented already? How do we configure the header cell click to goto the dayview from Monthview?